# Applet is taking huge time to load Jar files mentioned in archive tag

Tags: java, jar, applet, compression

In my web, I am using PDFBox to render PDF file and print PDF file from the byte on the client side.

For this I am using applet, to search the printer and print the document.

But Apache PDFBox is having size of 9.30 MB. Which is too large and applet takes more time to load the file.

Can anyone suggest me a way to reduce the applet start up time and load the file on the spot when required?  OR Is there any way to compress the JAR file ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Obfuscate the code.  Doing so often reduces the size of the Jar significantly, but might cause problems with external APIs.
2. Use a higher compression using [Pack 200](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/pack200.html).  See the [Pack200 and Version Download: Usage in Applet Tag](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/tools/pack200.html#pack200AppletTag) for further details.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Andrew Thompson. I tried the following command on jar file ...D:\TEST\SEL DEV\JAR Singner>pack200  -r PDFBox.jar. But it does not make more sense. It re-created the jar file that varies only 1 KB in size. So it is not making a big change.

Comment: I also tried the following command.. but the same case as above..D:\TEST\SEL DEV\JAR Singner>pack200 PDFBox.pack.gz PDFBox.jar. Here also the newly create pack.gz file varies from 2 KB as compared to original jar file. So its not great change for us

Comment: I am surprised at your result.  Maybe you should start a new question devoted to pack200.  I have to admit I have never needed to use it, but had heard good reports of 40%+ compression beyond typical Jar..